# How to get top most screens route name

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigation

I am following this [Navigate with named routes](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes). Where I am passing a route name to view the new screen.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
```

So, what I need is the topmost screens routeName. in this case `/second`.
How can I get it?

Comment: check `ModalRoute.of` static method

Comment: hi @pskink, used `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name` but its returning `/` all the time

Comment: are you sure you use a correct context?

Comment: I need that from another sub widget

Answer (score 2):

other than `Modal.of(context)`, flutter doesn't provide any easier way to get the latest route name.
but anyone who is using route handling using `onRouteGenerated` property can do this

```
class AllRoutes{
  static String _lastRoute = "/";

  static Route onGenerated(RouteSettings settings){
    _lastRoute = settings.name;
    //handle route changes here rather passing the route Map to the App
  }  
  static String get lastRoute=>_lastRoute;
}
```

and add the static method as the `onGenerateRoute` property value of the App

```
MaterialApp(
   onGenerateRoute: AllRoutes.onGenerated,
  )
```

and get the last route like this

```
var lastRoute = AllRoutes.lastRoute
```

You could add this as a extension to `Navigator` so you could feel at home ;)

Comment: Never gets called here ;-/

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: sorry think it was my logic problem.

Comment: It wont get updated if we pop from top route to the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

You can register as an observer in navigatorObservers in MaterialApp to get notified when routes change, and keep the last one:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'test',
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      navigatorObservers: [
        RouteObserver(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class RouteObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  String? lastRoute;

  @override
  void didReplace({Route? newRoute, Route? oldRoute}) {
    lastRoute = newRoute?.settings.name;
  }

  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    lastRoute = route.settings.name;
  }

  @override    
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    lastRoute = previousRoute?.settings.name;
  }

  @override    
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    lastRoute = previousRoute?.settings.name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String? getTopRouteName (BuildContext context) {
  String? top;
  Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
    top = route.settings.name;
    return true;
  });
  return top;
}
```

Unfortunately, `Navigator` does not provide such API. But the top most route name could be found through this tricky method, which is trying to pop the top most route, but prevented by the return value `true`.